# Constructibility of the regular 17-gon

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, fields, euclidean-geometry

There is a standard construction of  a regular heptadecagon by H.W. Richmond (1893) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon ) (As anyone knows, it was Gauss who found out that it is possible to do this with a ruler and a compass. It is worth  to be noted that he was 19 at the time and that this discovery was among the reasons why he has chosen mathematics rather then languages for a career.)  For the sake of clarity, here is the diagram. 
[image]

The construction works because (or if)

$$\angle AOP_3=\frac{3}{17}\cdot 2\pi.$$

Now, three questions.

Q1. Is it possible to prove this statement using Hilbert's axioms?

Q2. Is it possible to   prove this statement using  Tarski's axioms? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms)

Q3. What the proof, if written in the style of Euclid, may be like?

A few comments. First, it almost certainly does not matter *which* construction is chosen, but some choice it better to be made here. Second, first two questions are, in fact, reference requests. (Nobody doubts that the answer is yes.) 
Finally, the last question is about history of mathematics. (Not an alternative history where the construction were discovered by ancient geometers, but the real one.)  Invention of algebraic methods  made possible nice proofs in place of cumbersome ones, and one may be curious   about how much advantage it gives in comparison to the ancient geometric algebra.

Comment: I think Euclid would say (something along the lines of) "Where did you get that glowing box?" Since he could verify the steps and the lengths, he would likely say (something along the lines of) "That's great? Have they trisected the angle yet?" Gerhard "Yes, 'Lines' Is A Pun" Paseman, 2018.07.09.

Comment: One has a fiddly but definite algorithmic construction, and it would be boring but straightforward to write a Euclidean proof.  What is to doubt?  (The purely algebraic part of it is significant in providing an *upper*, not a *lower*, bound on the set of $n$ for which an $n$-gon is constructible.)

Comment: Are you worried that Euclid lacked the ability to talk about numbers in some relevant way?

Comment: Did Euclid know that an angle trisector would let you construct a regular heptagon?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems based on a false premise

Comment: @YemonChoi, do you know what the premise *is*?  (I'm not sure, and the poster doesn't seem inclined to clarify.)

Comment: @LSpice My guess is that the OP has some dichotomy in mind between Cartesian geometry and Euclidean geometry, and so thinks that invoking trig is somehow dodgy. I agree it is not clear what part of the constructions given on the Wikipedia page are supposed to be problematic for the OP

Comment: I think OP raises a valid question (though perhaps not research-level): can the proof of the validity of this-or-that construction of the regular $17$-gon attained using modern algebra be translated in Euclid's axioms?  I don't think it is obvious, but it is a consequence of theorem 5.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4315 (Avigad, Dean & Mumma, *A formal system for Euclid's Elements*), which states that every statement true in every ordered field closed under positive square roots is provable in Euclid's *Elements*.

Comment: I seem to recall reading in Martin Gardner that someone actually literally did the construction of a 17-gon with straightedge and compass.

Comment: Jim Conant--see "heptadecagon" in wikipedia for a construction going back to 1893. I think the story you're thinking of is that of the regular 65537-gon---supposedly an advisor, trying to get rid of a student, told him to provide the geometric construction--and he did.

Comment: @paulMonsky: yes, thanks that's the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen got the question right and I will have a look at the reference. I also changed the question up, to maybe clarify it, but feedback is welcome!

Comment: Hilbert's axiomatization of geometry would surely be overkill, as it brings in second-order axioms. Tarski's first-order axioms (or descendants thereof) would be more reasonable, although still overkill as they basically provide for coordinatization over a real closed field for any given model. The most intriguing possibility was mentioned by Gro-Tsen (work of Avigad, Dean, and Mumma) and I would guess this is closely related to the field of Euclidean numbers: mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanNumber.html.

Comment: Tarski's geometry is decidable, so every statement can be proved either true or false. Clearly, you can't prove that the construction is false (because it's true), so there must be a proof that the construction works.

Comment: @ Adam P. Goucher : A good point.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher In order for the decidability to be used, you have to formulate the statement (*"the regular 17-gon is constructable"* or *"this set of points is the regular 17-gon"*) in the language of Tarski's geometry (TG). (Only then you can really say that it is a statement of TG) But this does not seem immediate to me, since I am not sure if you can actually define angles in TG. So you would have to define *regular polygone* in a different way then "equilateral and equiangular".

Comment: @Kettel The statement you can formulate is "this set of points is the regular 17-gon". Equilateral is equivalent to all lengths $P_i P_{i+1}$ being equal (by definition). If, in addition, all lengths $P_i P_{i+2}$ are equal, then the polygon is also equiangular (apply SSS congruence to triangles triples of consecutive vertices). The converse also holds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question. If you can construct a triangle $T$ with angles $2\pi/17, 16\pi/17, 16\pi/17$ you can construct a regular $17$-gon. If you can construct $\cos \pi/17$ you can construct one half of $T$ and hence the whole $T.$ What part of this would escape Euclid?

Comment: The way I understand OP's question, the problem is not the distinction between $\cos(2\pi/17)$ and the regular heptadecagon, the problem is whether the proof that this-or-that construction of either using modern algebra (and manipulations of square roots) can be translated in Euclid's axioms.  See my comment on the question and the reference to Avigad, Dean & Mumma's result.